# Fixing gap between sections in different media queries while using bootstrap columns

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, media-queries

I am practicing web developing with AngularJS. I have a ul called itemList which looks like this in my app.js file

```
bootstrapColumnMdWidth: "6",
itemList: [
              "Item 1",
              "Item 2",
              "Item 3",
              "Item 4",
              "Item 5",
              "Item 6",
              "Item 7",
           ]
},{
bootstrapColumnMdWidth: "6",
itemList: [
              "Item 8",
              "Item 9",
              "Item 10",
              "Item 11",
              "Item 12",
              "Item 13",
              "Item 14",
            ]
        },{
```

bootstrapColumnWidth is a dynamic class that I made through which I assign bootstrap column width to an element. I wanted the items from the two lists to be next to each other, so each itemList is given width 6.

So on my laptop, this looks like this:

```
          "Item 1",           "Item 8",
          "Item 2",           "Item 9",
          "Item 3",           "Item 10",
          "Item 4",           "Item 11",
          "Item 5",           "Item 12",
          "Item 6",           "Item 13",
          "Item 7",           "Item 14",
```

This is exactly what I wanted; Two lists that are spaced equally with two 6 columns.

Now the problem that I am having is that, since I have two itemLists instead of one, when my view is mobile, it will look like this:

```
          "Item 1",
          "Item 2",
          "Item 3",
          "Item 4",
          "Item 5",
          "Item 6",
          "Item 7",

          "Item 8",
          "Item 9",
          "Item 10",
          "Item 11",
          "Item 12",
          "Item 13",
          "Item 14",
```

The gap between the lists is an issue for me. I still want to keep my two lists separate with their respective width values, but on a mobile phone, I want to have all the items displayed without the gap in between. Is there any quick fix for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remove the 'margin-bottom' from the first list using CSS for the xs breakpoint:

```
@media (max-width: $screen-xs-max) {
   .parent-element ul:first-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: That's great. Upvote and accept as an answer if this has solved your problem please.

Comment: I don't think I can since I am new here.